# What is the physical significance of arithmetic operations?

Tags: arithmetic, computational-mathematics, philosophy, foundations

Here is an example of what I mean by physical significance:

When we use some geometric or trigonometric identity, let us say Pythagoras' theorem to calculate the length of the diagonal of a field, according to my understanding what we are doing is using the property of space (and/or the structure of our mind which perceives space) to use the consistent behaviour of space to predict the length of the diagonal without directly measuring it.

If that is not a wrong way of looking at mathematics, my question is, what exactly are we doing when we perform calculations such as 941 * 67 = 63047 on paper?

Comment: According to **your** point of view, when we perform calculations such as 941 * 67 = 63047 on paper we are predicting the total amount of eggs we will have if we buy 67 box with 941 eggs each.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. I understand that part. My doubt is about the power of the arithmetic algorithms - where does that come from? For instance in my example the "power" can be said to come from the consistent property of space which enables us to predict. when we have a number k represented using a set of symbols, and another l, represented with another set (arrangement) of symbols, and we have an symbolic manipulation algorithm to determine the set of symbols to represent m which is equivalent to k*l. This algorithmic process seems to have revolutionized human civilizations..[continued]

Comment: I understand that numbers are a way of our mind to perceive things distinctly. And I understand that process of addition and subtraction are consistent just as the relationship between sides and diagonals of a rectangle are. However, while I can understand where the power of science comes from - namely from the observation of natural phenomenon and their organization -  or even of geometry, as exemplified above, I am not so sure about the source of the power of arithmetic. For example if we were in a civilization which could count but didn't have a positional number system, I wonder what

Comment: impact it could have on the scientific and technological progress. I guess huge. If so, the positional number system and arithmetic operational algorithms have played a central part in human scientific and technological progress. The fact that we are able to denote l * k by another notation m and not stuck with l * k seems to have played an important part. What more is behind it beyond say the compactness of using positional system than using tally marks?